# Auto-import Less mixins inside SFC

Tags: vuejs3, less, vite, nuxt3

I'm migrating a project from vue 3 to nuxt 3 and my previous project used Less but outside of Vue's SFC styles blocks, it so use a lot of less mixins but for the migration I'm moving all the css to it's dedicated SFC to have easier maintaining. The issue with that is the mixins I've mentionned before, just moving the stylings won't work because the mixins are then undefined inside the SFC.

I've tried some stuff with the vite `preprocessorOptions`, imported the main less files in either the app root or the `css` array of nuxt config but no matter what I try mixins are still undefined in the SFCs.

The only suitable way i found to properly import the mixins without adding the whole styling in each sfc is to use `@import(reference)` with the main less file, which don't import the whole styling but only what's needed.

I'm wondering if there is  a way to properly configure vite to be able to call mixins in SFCs without having to use import reference, and if that's not possible is there a better way than import ref or is it possible to tell nuxt to automatically add the import line to SFCs.

Comment: Not sure about LESS, but SASS/SCSS auto-import works with `preprocessorOptions`